# "Responsibility" stereotype in UML

Tags: uml

According to the UML spec we can denote a dependency by means of << Responsibility >> stereotype (chap. 22.3 Standard Stereotypes)

Here is the definition of it from the spec:

> A contract or an obligation of an element in its relationship to other
>   elements.

Could you give an example of usage of such stereotype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some other definitions:

> - The source element is responsible for the target element [[Weilkiens, 
>     Oestereich 2010]](https://books.google.de/books?id=k8JjTf6pq1oC).
> - ... signifies that the client has some kind of obligation to the supplier
>     [[Scott 2004]](https://books.google.de/books?id=XdhG2EXWXC4C).
> - The Comment at the supplier end of the Dependency defines the 
>     responsibilities of the client class or component [[MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd465146.aspx).

Example:

[image]